# Replace the last element in RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, text, replace, str-replace

I have RDD as below:

```
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07] "GET /" 304 0
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/ksclogo-medium.gif" 304 0
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/MOSAIC-logosmall.gif" 304 0
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/USA-logosmall.gif" 304 0
 ix-esc-ca2-07.ix.netcom.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:09] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif" 200 1713
 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/WORLD-logosmall.gif" 304 0
 slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /history/skylab/skylab.html" 200 1687
 piweba4y.prodigy.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/launchmedium.gif" 200 11853
 slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:11] "GET /history/skylab/skylab-small.gif" 200 9202
```

I want to check if last element(token) is hyphen and replace it with zero if so. My code is below:

```
 def process_row(row):
 words = row.replace('"', '').split(' ')
 words.map(lambda row: 0 if x[5] == '-' else  x[5])
 return words

 nasa = (
 nasa_raw.flatMap(process_row)
 )

for row in nasa.take(5):
print(row)
```

When I try to run I get an error **object has no attribute  map**

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`split` returns a python list which does not have `map`. You may use the following instead

```py
words = map(lambda row: 0 if x[5] == '-' else  x[5],words)
```